# Mac Mini server will randomly shutdown

Tags: mac-mini, shutdown

A Mac mini at one of our customers has started to randomly shutdown, yesterday was second time in less than a month. This system hosts the customers shared folders and a Windows VM for their critical operations. The system is connected to an UPS as well.

This is really worrying as we could not find any hints as to why the system shuts down in the logs (see below). We only see the last events around 22:48 before we got an employee to restart it at 09:22. Not even a crash reporter at startup.

Last month shutdown happened at night and we just go a new one this night. This system has been up and running with this config for more than 4 years...

Are we missing something apart the fact that we need to push the customer to allow us to update it to High Sierra or later (costs, VMware compatibility issues, etc...)?

Any hints appreciated, thanks.

Olivier

Major logs between 22:00 and 9:23 after restart of the system.

Mac Mini Late 2014, i7, 16GB RAM, OS X 10.10.5 (we only do security updates on this system)

```
All messages
01/07/19 21:47:37.193 SystemUIServer[234]: Attempt to use XPC with a MachService that has HideUntilCheckIn set. This will result in unpredictable behavior: com.apple.backupd.status.xpc
01/07/19 21:57:00.944 EscrowSecurityAlert[536]:  SOSCCThisDeviceIsInCircle SOSCCThisDeviceIsInCircle!! 12
01/07/19 21:57:00.960 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.quicklook[6932]) Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.quicklook
01/07/19 22:22:42.931 TeamViewer_Service[52]: TVRouterClock: received router time: 20190701T202242.917978
01/07/19 22:22:42.931 TeamViewer_Service[52]: TVRouterClock Schedule next request in 43200 seconds
01/07/19 22:22:42.932 TeamViewer_Desktop[324]: IpcRouterClock: received router time: 20190701T202242.917978
01/07/19 22:22:42.932 TeamViewer[321]: IpcRouterClock: received router time: 20190701T202242.917978
01/07/19 22:22:42.932 TeamViewer_Desktop[2930]: IpcRouterClock: received router time: 20190701T202242.917978
01/07/19 22:45:55.788 com.apple.backupd-helper[68]: Attempt to use XPC with a MachService that has HideUntilCheckIn set. This will result in unpredictable behavior: com.apple.backupd.status.xpc
01/07/19 22:46:26.000 com.apple.backupd[6936]: Starting automatic backup
01/07/19 22:46:26.013 com.apple.backupd[6936]: Backing up to /dev/disk3s2: /Volumes/<REMOVED>-BKP/Backups.backupdb
01/07/19 22:46:26.124 com.apple.backupd[6936]: Will copy (150 KB) from Macintosh HD
01/07/19 22:46:26.124 com.apple.backupd[6936]: Found 37 files (150 KB) needing backup
01/07/19 22:46:26.131 com.apple.backupd[6936]: 1.97 GB required (including padding), 127.61 GB available
01/07/19 22:46:27.133 com.apple.backupd[6936]: Copied 41 items (150 KB) from volume Macintosh HD. Linked 430.
01/07/19 22:46:28.219 com.apple.backupd[6936]: Created new backup: 2019-07-01-224628
01/07/19 22:46:28.238 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
01/07/19 22:46:28.000 kernel[0]: hfs: mounted Recovery HD on device disk0s3
01/07/19 22:46:28.557 mds[58]: (Volume.Normal:2464) volume:0x7f81da900800 ********** Bootstrapped Creating a default store:0 SpotLoc:(null) SpotVerLoc:(null) occlude:0 /Volumes/Recovery HD
01/07/19 22:46:28.601 fseventsd[45]: Logging disabled completely for device:1: /Volumes/Recovery HD
01/07/19 22:46:28.670 mdworker[6938]: (ImportBailout.Error:1325) Asked to exit for Diskarb
01/07/19 22:46:28.671 mdworker[6937]: (ImportBailout.Error:1325) Asked to exit for Diskarb
01/07/19 22:46:28.671 mdworker[6939]: (ImportBailout.Error:1325) Asked to exit for Diskarb
01/07/19 22:46:28.000 kernel[0]: hfs: unmount initiated on Recovery HD on device disk0s3
01/07/19 22:46:28.699 com.apple.backupd[6936]: Starting post-backup thinning
01/07/19 22:46:28.792 com.apple.backupd[6936]: Deleted /Volumes/<REMOVED>-BKP/Backups.backupdb/<REMOVED>’s Mac mini server/2019-06-30-221917 (201 KB)
01/07/19 22:46:28.793 com.apple.backupd[6936]: Post-backup thinning complete: 1 expired backups removed
01/07/19 22:46:28.815 com.apple.backupd[6936]: Backup completed successfully.
01/07/19 22:48:30.076 SystemUIServer[234]: Attempt to use XPC with a MachService that has HideUntilCheckIn set. This will result in unpredictable behavior: com.apple.backupd.status.xpc
02/07/19 09:23:11.000 bootlog[0]: BOOT_TIME 1562052191 0
02/07/19 09:23:12.000 syslogd[41]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.AccountPolicyHelper" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
02/07/19 09:23:12.000 syslogd[41]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.authd" sharing output destination "/var/log/asl" with ASL Module "com.apple.asl".
Output parameters from ASL Module "com.apple.asl" override any specified in ASL Module "com.apple.authd".
02/07/19 09:23:12.000 syslogd[41]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.authd" sharing output destination "/var/log/system.log" with ASL Module "com.apple.asl".
Output parameters from ASL Module "com.apple.asl" override any specified in ASL Module "com.apple.authd".
02/07/19 09:23:12.000 syslogd[41]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.authd" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
02/07/19 09:23:12.000 syslogd[41]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.awdd" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
02/07/19 09:23:12.000 syslogd[41]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.callhistory.asl.conf" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
02/07/19 09:23:12.000 syslogd[41]: Configuration Notice:
ASL Module "com.apple.cloudd" claims selected messages.
Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.


Diagnostic and Usage Messages
01/07/19 21:57:00.981 AddressBookSourceSync[6930]: com.apple.message.domain: com.apple.AddressBook.accounts.summary
com.apple.message.summarize: YES
com.apple.message.carddav_accounts: 0
com.apple.message.disabled_accounts: 1
com.apple.message.enabled_accounts: 1
com.apple.message.exchange_accounts: 0
com.apple.message.ldap_accounts: 0
com.apple.message.total_accounts: 3
SenderMachUUID: 538C29C5-D94E-3E82-983E-6268E2727E28

01/07/19 22:57:01.100 AddressBookSourceSync[6949]: com.apple.message.domain: com.apple.AddressBook.accounts.summary
com.apple.message.summarize: YES
com.apple.message.carddav_accounts: 0
com.apple.message.disabled_accounts: 1
com.apple.message.enabled_accounts: 1
com.apple.message.exchange_accounts: 0
com.apple.message.ldap_accounts: 0
com.apple.message.total_accounts: 3
SenderMachUUID: 538C29C5-D94E-3E82-983E-6268E2727E28

01/07/19 23:27:57.538 WindowServer[141]: com.apple.message.domain: com.apple.windowserver.displayarrangement.v2
com.apple.message.ndisplays: 1
com.apple.message.nrotated: 0
com.apple.message.clamshell: 0
com.apple.message.applemirror: 0
com.apple.message.hidpiw: 0
SenderMachUUID: DE442EA4-37E9-305A-849A-B9A9D8C57AD2

02/07/19 09:23:13.820 airportd[55]: com.apple.message.domain: com.apple.wifi.bluetooth_coex
com.apple.message.bandwidth_utilization: 0
com.apple.message.clamshell_mode: No
com.apple.message.sco_device_count: 0
com.apple.message.a2dp_device_count: 0
com.apple.message.frequency_band: 2.4GHz
com.apple.message.per_chain_thermal_throttling: Off,Off,Off
com.apple.message.desense_high_rssi: 0
com.apple.message.desense_low_rssi: 0
com.apple.message.per_chain_ack_policy: Off,Off,Off
com.apple.message.mode: Off
com.apple.message.per_chain_transmit_power_offset: 0,0,0
com.apple.message.desense: No
com.apple.message.per_chain_power: Off,Off,Off
SenderMachUUID: C0300690-DDD5-3430-B727-8D5D765814DD

02/07/19 09:23:16.000 kernel[0]: com.apple.message.domain: com.apple.commssw.ethernet.broadcom.link
com.apple.message.signature: 100-Megabit
com.apple.message.signature2: Full-duplex
com.apple.message.signature3: Symmetric flow-control
com.apple.message.signature4: EEE disabled

02/07/19 09:23:16.000 kernel[0]: com.apple.message.domain: com.apple.commssw.ethernet.broadcom.load
com.apple.message.signature: 0x14E4
com.apple.message.signature2: 0x1686
com.apple.message.signature3: {Asymmetric-Pause=1}{Pause=1}{100baseTX-full-duplex=1}{100baseTX-half-duplex=1}{10baseT-full-duplex=1}{10baseT-half-duplex=1}{1000baseT-full-duplex=0}{100baseTX-EEE=0}{1000baseT-EEE=0}
com.apple.message.signature4: 1

02/07/19 09:23:19.811 loginwindow[92]: getgrouplist called triggering group enumeration
com.apple.message.value: 256
com.apple.message.domain: com.apple.system.libinfo
com.apple.message.result: noop
com.apple.message.signature: getgrouplist
SenderMachUUID: 66748489-BF5B-3A2B-8A19-2711537A4BCB

02/07/19 09:23:19.818 mds[58]: getgrouplist called triggering group enumeration
com.apple.message.value: 16
com.apple.message.domain: com.apple.system.libinfo
com.apple.message.result: noop
com.apple.message.signature: getgrouplist
SenderMachUUID: CF80CBCE-F59D-3A8D-8DC3-DCB511AFE400

02/07/19 09:22:21.260 activateSettings[235]: com.apple.message.domain: com.apple.security.requireAdminPasswordForPrefs
com.apple.message.requireadminpasswordforprefs: Password required
SenderMachUUID: 08B7041A-0EC0-386D-A3EB-B26A4B9741A4

02/07/19 09:22:21.265 activateSettings[235]: com.apple.message.domain: com.apple.systempreferences.3rdpartycount
com.apple.message.3rdpartycount: 0
SenderMachUUID: 08B7041A-0EC0-386D-A3EB-B26A4B9741A4

02/07/19 09:22:21.792 sharingd[255]: com.apple.message.domain: com.apple.AddressBook.accounts.summary
com.apple.message.summarize: YES
com.apple.message.carddav_accounts: 0
com.apple.message.disabled_accounts: 1
com.apple.message.enabled_accounts: 1
com.apple.message.exchange_accounts: 0
com.apple.message.ldap_accounts: 0
com.apple.message.total_accounts: 3
SenderMachUUID: D5FDA5E8-DA48-321D-AC27-FCB8AE01E672

02/07/19 09:22:21.804 Unknown[233]: com.apple.message.domain: com.apple.assumes.failure
com.apple.message.signature: 5C829202-962E-3744-8B50-00D38CC88E84:62447
com.apple.message.signature2: 0x89
com.apple.message.signature3: libxpc.dylib
com.apple.message.summarize: YES
SenderMachUUID: 3BB4CFA3-DFA6-3A9E-AF82-3DF5397AD298


system log
Jul  1 21:57:00 <REMOVED>.local EscrowSecurityAlert[536]:  SOSCCThisDeviceIsInCircle SOSCCThisDeviceIsInCircle!! 12
Jul  1 21:57:00 <REMOVED> com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.quicklook[6932]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.quicklook
Jul  1 22:22:42 <REMOVED>.local TeamViewer_Service[52]: TVRouterClock: received router time: 20190701T202242.917978
Jul  1 22:22:42 <REMOVED>.local TeamViewer_Service[52]: TVRouterClock Schedule next request in 43200 seconds
Jul  1 22:22:42 <REMOVED>.local TeamViewer_Desktop[324]: IpcRouterClock: received router time: 20190701T202242.917978
Jul  1 22:22:42 <REMOVED>.local TeamViewer[321]: IpcRouterClock: received router time: 20190701T202242.917978
Jul  1 22:22:42 <REMOVED>.local TeamViewer_Desktop[2930]: IpcRouterClock: received router time: 20190701T202242.917978
Jul  1 22:45:55 <REMOVED>.local com.apple.backupd-helper[68]: Attempt to use XPC with a MachService that has HideUntilCheckIn set. This will result in unpredictable behavior: com.apple.backupd.status.xpc
Jul  1 22:46:26 <REMOVED>.local com.apple.backupd[6936]: Starting automatic backup
Jul  1 22:46:26 <REMOVED>.local com.apple.backupd[6936]: Backing up to /dev/disk3s2: /Volumes/<REMOVED>-BKP/Backups.backupdb
Jul  1 22:46:26 <REMOVED>.local com.apple.backupd[6936]: Will copy (150 KB) from Macintosh HD
Jul  1 22:46:26 <REMOVED>.local com.apple.backupd[6936]: Found 37 files (150 KB) needing backup
Jul  1 22:46:26 <REMOVED>.local com.apple.backupd[6936]: 1.97 GB required (including padding), 127.61 GB available
Jul  1 22:46:27 <REMOVED>.local com.apple.backupd[6936]: Copied 41 items (150 KB) from volume Macintosh HD. Linked 430.
Jul  1 22:46:28 <REMOVED>.local com.apple.backupd[6936]: Created new backup: 2019-07-01-224628
Jul  1 22:46:28 <REMOVED> com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
Jul  1 22:46:28 <REMOVED> kernel[0]: hfs: mounted Recovery HD on device disk0s3
Jul  1 22:46:28 <REMOVED>.local mds[58]: (Volume.Normal:2464) volume:0x7f81da900800 ********** Bootstrapped Creating a default store:0 SpotLoc:(null) SpotVerLoc:(null) occlude:0 /Volumes/Recovery HD
Jul  1 22:46:28 <REMOVED>.local fseventsd[45]: Logging disabled completely for device:1: /Volumes/Recovery HD
Jul  1 22:46:28 <REMOVED>.local mdworker[6938]: (ImportBailout.Error:1325) Asked to exit for Diskarb
Jul  1 22:46:28 <REMOVED>.local mdworker[6937]: (ImportBailout.Error:1325) Asked to exit for Diskarb
Jul  1 22:46:28 <REMOVED>.local mdworker[6939]: (ImportBailout.Error:1325) Asked to exit for Diskarb
Jul  1 22:46:28 <REMOVED> kernel[0]: hfs: unmount initiated on Recovery HD on device disk0s3
Jul  1 22:46:28 <REMOVED>.local com.apple.backupd[6936]: Starting post-backup thinning
Jul  1 22:46:28 <REMOVED>.local com.apple.backupd[6936]: Deleted /Volumes/<REMOVED>-BKP/Backups.backupdb/<REMOVED>’s Mac mini server/2019-06-30-221917 (201 KB)
Jul  1 22:46:28 <REMOVED>.local com.apple.backupd[6936]: Post-backup thinning complete: 1 expired backups removed
Jul  1 22:46:28 <REMOVED>.local com.apple.backupd[6936]: Backup completed successfully.
Jul  1 22:48:30 <REMOVED>.local SystemUIServer[234]: Attempt to use XPC with a MachService that has HideUntilCheckIn set. This will result in unpredictable behavior: com.apple.backupd.status.xpc
Jul  2 09:23:11 localhost bootlog[0]: BOOT_TIME 1562052191 0
Jul  2 09:23:12 localhost syslogd[41]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.AccountPolicyHelper" claims selected messages.
    Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Jul  2 09:23:12 localhost syslogd[41]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.authd" sharing output destination "/var/log/asl" with ASL Module "com.apple.asl".
    Output parameters from ASL Module "com.apple.asl" override any specified in ASL Module "com.apple.authd".
Jul  2 09:23:12 localhost syslogd[41]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.authd" sharing output destination "/var/log/system.log" with ASL Module "com.apple.asl".
    Output parameters from ASL Module "com.apple.asl" override any specified in ASL Module "com.apple.authd".
Jul  2 09:23:12 localhost syslogd[41]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.authd" claims selected messages.
    Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Jul  2 09:23:12 localhost syslogd[41]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.awdd" claims selected messages.
    Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Jul  2 09:23:12 localhost syslogd[41]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.callhistory.asl.conf" claims selected messages.
    Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Jul  2 09:23:12 localhost syslogd[41]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.cloudd" claims selected messages.
    Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.


CrashReporter log
EMPTY

powermanagement log 
Jul  1 21:57:31 <REMOVED>.local powerd[51] <Notice>: PID 6930(AddressBookSour) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "Address Book Source Sync" 00:00:30  id:0x1000006a5 [System: No Assertions]
Jul  1 22:46:28 <REMOVED>.local powerd[51] <Notice>: PID 42(UserEventAgent) Released BackgroundTask "com.apple.backupd-auto" 00:00:33  id:0xb000006e8 [System: No Assertions]
Jul  1 22:46:43 <REMOVED>.local powerd[51] <Notice>: PID 6940(diskmanagementd) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "com.apple.diskmanagementd" 00:00:15  id:0x1000006ec [System: No Assertions]
Jul  1 22:57:31 <REMOVED>.local powerd[51] <Notice>: PID 6949(AddressBookSour) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "Address Book Source Sync" 00:00:30  id:0x1000006fd [System: No Assertions]
Jul  2 09:23:12 localhost powerd[51] <Notice>: powerd process is started
Jul  2 09:23:12 localhost powerd[51] <Notice>: Summary- [System: No Assertions] Using AC
Jul  2 09:22:44 <REMOVED>.local powerd[51] <Notice>: PID 415(TeamViewer) Created PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "TeamViewer session is active" 00:00:00  id:0x50000016e [System: PrevIdle PrevDisp BGTask kDisp]
Jul  2 09:23:36 <REMOVED>.local powerd[51] <Notice>: PID 42(UserEventAgent) Released BackgroundTask "com.apple.metadata.mds.power" 00:00:21  id:0xb00000134 [System: PrevIdle PrevDisp kDisp]
Jul  2 09:24:23 <REMOVED>.local powerd[51] <Notice>: PID 487(AppleFileServer) Created NetworkClientActive "com.apple.AppleFileServer" 00:00:00  id:0x1100000175 [System: PrevIdle PrevDisp NetAcc kCPU kDisp]
Jul  2 09:25:16 <REMOVED>.local powerd[51] <Notice>: PID 488(smbd) Created NetworkClientActive "com.apple.smbd" 00:00:00  id:0x1100000179 [System: PrevIdle PrevDisp NetAcc kCPU kDisp]

performance log
Jul  1 21:03:19 <REMOVED>.local com.apple.performance.afpServer[2188] <Info>: 
Jul  1 22:04:06 <REMOVED>.local com.apple.performance.afpServer[2188] <Info>: 
Jul  1 22:08:14 <REMOVED>.local com.apple.performance.afpServer[2188] <Info>:
Jul  2 09:25:09 <REMOVED>.local com.apple.performance.afpServer[487] <Info>: 
Jul  2 09:25:15 <REMOVED>.local com.apple.performance.smbd.network[488] <Info>: 
Jul  2 09:25:16 <REMOVED>.local com.apple.performance.smbd.smb2[488] <Info>: 
Jul  2 09:26:10 <REMOVED>.local com.apple.performance.afpServer[487] <Info>: 
Jul  2 09:27:10 <REMOVED>.local com.apple.performance.afpServer[487] <Info>: 
Jul  2 09:28:10 <REMOVED>.local com.apple.performance.afpServer[487] <Info>: 
Jul  2 09:29:03 <REMOVED>.local com.apple.performance.smbd.network[488] <Info>: 
Jul  2 09:29:03 <REMOVED>.local com.apple.performance.smbd.smb2[488] <Info>: 

install log
Jul  1 18:42:02 <REMOVED>.local softwareupdated[218]: SoftwareUpdate: Fired early. Next check=02/07/19 06:40 (interval=86280.000000, A/C=YES)
Jul  1 18:42:02 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Jul  1 18:42:02 <REMOVED>.local softwareupdated[218]: BackgroundActivity: Finished Background Check Activity
Jul  1 18:42:02 <REMOVED>.local softwareupdate_notify_agent[6796]: Running for UpdatesAvailable
Jul  1 18:42:02 <REMOVED>.local softwareupdate_notify_agent[6796]: User not on-console
Jul  2 09:23:19 <REMOVED>.local softwareupdate_firstrun_tasks[87]: swscan.apple.com is available: TRUE
Jul  2 09:23:19 <REMOVED>.local softwareupdated[218]: softwareupdated: Starting with build 10.10.5 (14F2511)
Jul  2 09:22:22 <REMOVED>.local softwareupdated[218]: Adding client SUUpdateServiceClient pid=87, uid=200, installAuth=NO rights=(), transactions=0 (/System/Library/CoreServices/Software Update.app/Contents/Resources/softwareupdate_firstrun_tasks)
Jul  2 09:22:23 <REMOVED>.local softwareupdated[218]: BackgroundActivity: Activity check-in with Interval 21600 
Jul  2 09:22:23 <REMOVED>.local softwareupdated[218]: Removing client SUUpdateServiceClient pid=87, uid=200, installAuth=NO rights=(), transactions=0 (/System/Library/CoreServices/Software Update.app/Contents/Resources/softwareupdate_firstrun_tasks)

fsck_hfs log
/dev/rdisk0s3: fsck_hfs started at Mon Jul  1 21:45:35 2019
/dev/rdisk0s3: /dev/rdisk0s3: ** /dev/rdisk0s3 (NO WRITE)
/dev/rdisk0s3:    Executing fsck_hfs (version hfs-285).
QUICKCHECK ONLY; FILESYSTEM CLEAN
/dev/rdisk0s3: fsck_hfs completed at Mon Jul  1 21:45:35 2019


/dev/rdisk0s3: fsck_hfs started at Mon Jul  1 22:46:28 2019
/dev/rdisk0s3: /dev/rdisk0s3: ** /dev/rdisk0s3 (NO WRITE)
/dev/rdisk0s3:    Executing fsck_hfs (version hfs-285).
QUICKCHECK ONLY; FILESYSTEM CLEAN
/dev/rdisk0s3: fsck_hfs completed at Mon Jul  1 22:46:28 2019


fsck_hfs started at Tue Jul  2 09:23:11 2019
** /dev/rdisk1 (NO WRITE)
** Root file system
   Executing fsck_hfs (version hfs-285).
fsck_hfs completed at Tue Jul  2 09:23:11 2019


/dev/rdisk1: fsck_hfs started at Tue Jul  2 09:23:12 2019
/dev/rdisk1: /dev/rdisk1: ** /dev/rdisk1 (NO WRITE)
/dev/rdisk1: ** Root file system
/dev/rdisk1:    Executing fsck_hfs (version hfs-285).
/dev/rdisk1: fsck_hfs completed at Tue Jul  2 09:23:12 2019

DiagnosticMessages
Jul  1 21:27:57 <REMOVED>.local loginwindow[92] <Notice>: 
Jul  1 21:27:57 <REMOVED>.local loginwindow[92] <Notice>: 
Jul  1 21:57:00 <REMOVED>.local AddressBookSourceSync[6930] <Notice>: 
Jul  1 22:57:01 <REMOVED>.local AddressBookSourceSync[6949] <Notice>: 
Jul  1 23:27:57 <REMOVED>.local WindowServer[141] <Notice>: 
Jul  2 09:23:13 localhost airportd[55] <Notice>: 
Jul  2 09:23:16 <REMOVED> kernel[0] <Notice>: 
Jul  2 09:23:16 <REMOVED> kernel[0] <Notice>: 
Jul  2 09:23:19 <REMOVED>.local loginwindow[92] <Notice>: getgrouplist called triggering group enumeration
Jul  2 09:23:19 <REMOVED>.local mds[58] <Notice>: getgrouplist called triggering group enumeration
Jul  2 09:22:20 <REMOVED>.local loginwindow[92] <Debug>: 
Jul  2 09:22:21 <REMOVED>.local WindowServer[146] <Notice>: 
Jul  2 09:22:21 <REMOVED>.local activateSettings[235] <Notice>: 
Jul  2 09:22:21 <REMOVED>.local activateSettings[235] <Notice>: 
Jul  2 09:22:21 <REMOVED>.local sharingd[255] <Notice>: 
Jul  2 09:22:21 <REMOVED> Unknown[233] <Error>: 
Jul  2 09:22:22 <REMOVED>.local soagent[284] <Notice>: 
Jul  2 09:22:23 <REMOVED>.local CalendarAgent[281] <Notice>: 
Jul  2 09:22:23 <REMOVED>.local CalNCService[286] <Notice>: 
Jul  2 09:22:23 <REMOVED>.local callservicesd[290] <Notice>: 
Jul  2 09:22:27 <REMOVED>.local AddressBookManager[436] <Notice>: 
Jul  2 09:22:28 <REMOVED>.local findNames[452] <Notice>: 
Jul  2 09:22:28 <REMOVED>.local diagnostics_agent[426] <Debug>: 
Jul  2 09:22:29 <REMOVED>.local cloudpaird[422] <Notice>: 
Jul  2 09:22:29 <REMOVED>.local diagnostics_agent[426] <Notice>: 
Jul  2 09:22:36 <REMOVED>.local loginwindow[92] <Debug>: 
Jul  2 09:24:08 <REMOVED>.local AppleFileServer[487] <Notice>: getgrouplist called triggering group enumeration

authd log
Jul  1 21:46:05 --- last message repeated 4 times ---
Jul  1 22:46:26 <REMOVED>.local authd[129]: Succeeded authorizing right 'com.apple.ServiceManagement.daemons.modify' by client '/usr/libexec/UserEventAgent' [42] for authorization created by '/usr/libexec/UserEventAgent' [42] (12,0)
Jul  1 22:46:26 <REMOVED>.local authd[129]: Succeeded authorizing right 'com.apple.ServiceManagement.daemons.modify' by client '/usr/libexec/UserEventAgent' [42] for authorization created by '/usr/libexec/UserEventAgent' [42] (12,0)
Jul  1 22:46:58 --- last message repeated 4 times ---
Jul  2 09:23:13 localhost authd[129]: Succeeded authorizing right 'com.apple.ServiceManagement.daemons.modify' by client '/usr/libexec/UserEventAgent' [42] for authorization created by '/usr/libexec/UserEventAgent' [42] (12,0)
Jul  2 09:23:19 <REMOVED>.local authd[129]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.login.console' by client '/System/Library/CoreServices/loginwindow.app' [92] for authorization created by '/System/Library/CoreServices/loginwindow.app' [92] (3,0)
Jul  2 09:22:20 <REMOVED>.local authd[129]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.login.done' by client '/System/Library/CoreServices/loginwindow.app' [92] for authorization created by '/System/Library/CoreServices/loginwindow.app' [92] (2,0)
Jul  2 09:22:21 <REMOVED>.local authd[129]: Succeeded authorizing right 'system.services.systemconfiguration.network' by client '/usr/libexec/UserEventAgent' [220] for authorization created by '/usr/libexec/UserEventAgent' [220] (0,0)
Jul  2 09:22:51 --- last message repeated 1 time ---

accountpolicy log
Jul  1 15:09:09 (72.6247) SecondsUntilAuthenticationsExpire completed: record "_krbfast", result: never expires.
Jul  1 15:09:09 (72.6248) AuthenticationAllowed completed: record "<REMOVED>", result: Success (0).
Jul  1 15:09:09 (72.6249) SecondsUntilPasswordExpires completed: record "<REMOVED>", result: never expires.
Jul  1 15:09:09 (72.6250) SecondsUntilAuthenticationsExpire completed: record "<REMOVED>", result: never expires.
Jul  1 15:09:09 (72.6251) AuthenticationAllowed completed: record "localhost", result: Success (0).
Jul  1 15:09:09 (72.6252) SecondsUntilPasswordExpires completed: record "localhost", result: never expires.
Jul  1 15:09:09 (72.6253) SecondsUntilAuthenticationsExpire completed: record "localhost", result: never expires.
Jul  1 15:09:09 (72.6254) AuthenticationAllowed completed: record "<REMOVED>", result: Success (0).
Jul  1 15:09:09 (72.6255) SecondsUntilPasswordExpires completed: record "<REMOVED>", result: never expires.
Jul  1 15:09:09 (72.6256) SecondsUntilAuthenticationsExpire completed: record "<REMOVED>", result: never expires.
Jul  2 09:23:19 Account Policy Helper agent starting
Jul  2 09:23:19 (72.1) AuthenticationAllowed completed: record "<REMOVED>", result: Success (0).
Jul  2 09:23:19 (72.2) AuthenticationAllowed completed: record "<REMOVED>", result: Success (0).
Jul  2 09:23:19 (72.3) AuthenticationAllowed completed: record "<REMOVED>", result: Success (0).
Jul  2 09:23:19 (72.4) AuthenticationAllowed completed: record "<REMOVED>", result: Success (0).
Jul  2 09:23:19 (72.5) AuthenticationAllowed completed: record "<REMOVED>", result: Success (0).
Jul  2 09:24:07 (72.6) AuthenticationAllowed completed: record "<REMOVED>", result: Success (0).
```